# Ruby koan 124 - Are these symbols spontaneously changing type?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to get a categorical answer on how (and why) symbols appear to change type.

I had learned that symbols that end with a colon were an alternate syntax for declaring a symbol, usually used to populate hashes.

Koan number 124 has added more ambiguity to my (non)understanding by doing the following:

```
def method_with_keyword_arguments(one: 1, two: 'two')
  [one, two]
end
```

This page:
http://chriszetter.com/blog/2012/11/02/keyword-arguments-in-ruby-2-dot-0/
says `Keyword arguments in the method definition must be symbols given in the new-style hash syntax` but then what appear to be symbols in the parameters of the method are then method variables in the returned Array.

Can symbols change 'type' without even being changed by a method? Or, in this case, is there a method I'm not seeing that's changing the type? And if the type doesn't matter, why does it appear to change? Or can symbols be referred to without a colon?

If I'm wrong about any of this, please feel free to correct me and let me know what actually IS going on! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, symbols cannot change type on their own**, but when you're using `one` or `two` in your example, **you are using variables with similar names**, provided by Ruby based on your method definition, **not the symbols themselves**.

Consider a hash: when you have a hash `a = { one: 1, two: '1234' }` and you write `a[:one]` you don't get a symbol, but an appropriate value. So `:one` still is a symbol, but with `[a[:one], a[:two]]` you will get `[1, '1234']` array, not `[:one, :two]`.

Comment: I understand (I hope) that symbols point to a value. I'd like to understand how the variables in the return Array 'know' to refer to the values that the symbols in the method arguments point to. Is it just that their names are similar?

Comment: @moosefetcher symbols are not a pointers - they do not point to a value. They are just a regular ruby objects, basicaly - immutable strings. They are commonly used as a way to name/index something. And yes, you can use variable `one`, that Ruby provides to you in your method, just because you named an argument with such symbol.

Comment: OK, so it's the HASH that makes a symbol point to a value (key/value pairs)! Otherwise they ARE the 'value' in a way. Thanks. And I understand now that the variables are created by Ruby because of the corresponding symbols.

Comment: @moosefetcher not all variables, just named in method definition.

Comment: Sorry - I was talking about just the variables that correspond to the method arguments. In other news, I've just had another look at a form_for page and a line like `f.label :name` REALLY makes it look like a symbol points to another value (the current_user's name in this case). So my understanding of THAT remains somewhat vague.

Comment: @moosefetcher `f.label` here is a `label` metod call to `f` object with symbol `:name` as an argument, which will suggest it to look for `:name`-named attribute in current_user.
You can use symbols as method names in `send` and `try` methods: for example, `f.label :name` == `f.send :label, :name`, except that `send` does not care about method being public, protected or private.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68487/discussion-between-moosefetcher-and-ivan-kolmycheck).

Answer (score 0):

There are no symbols here. `one` and `two` are parameters, parameters become local variable variables in the method body.

In

```
def foo(bar:, baz:)
```

`bar` and `baz` are no more symbols than they are in

```
def foo(bar, baz)
```

In the first case they are keyword parameters, in the second case they are positional parameters, other than that, there is no difference. In the parameter list, they are parameter placeholders, in the method body, they become local variables bound to arguments.